# Cant figure this boolean out

Tags: java

boolean expression that tests whether number is negative. Specifically, the boolean expression should evaluate to true if number is possitive and false otherwise.

```
bool test(int a)
{
    if(( a>=1 && a<=100) || a < 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Which expressions have you tried? If we see your work so far we can try to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @YassinHajaj no because if a = -1 this would evaluate to true and OP does not want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't even know why I did this, you have shown absolutely zero effort on such a simple problem, just think, here is the reverse, solve it yourself.

```
boolean isNegative = a < 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that takes the number as an argument. You then check if the number is greater than or equal to zero. If it is not return nothing. In essence, anything returned will be evaluated as true, otherwise it will evaluate as false. For example:

```
boolean testNumber(long number) {
    return number >= 0;
}
```

Comment: any reason why using long ?

Comment: Anything smaller can be converted into a long with no loss of data, so this is usable for all integer types

Comment: OP is using int that's for a start :). Maybe OP does not know what long is ? though of that :) ? One does not simply overkill the answer to a question from confused beginner as they can become more confused

Answer (score 0):

Your example you could be simplified to:

```
bool test(int a)
{
    return a>=1 && a<=100) || a < 0
}
```

But this will evaluate any int that is in range (Integer.MIN, 100), and you need only numbers that are positive

If you only want to check if a number is positive, than you can do t like:

Traditional way (before JDK8)

```
boolean isPositive(int value){
   return value >= 0;
}
```

Or with Predicates (Guava, Jdk8)

```
Predicate<Integer> isPositive = x -> x>=0;
```